# Allow checkbox to be selected only once

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have VF pop up message which displays a list of records. There is a first checkbox where user check to select the association and there is a second checkbox where user would define the primary of the selection. So in the second checkbox I would want user to select only once across of the data set. Both first and second checkbox are part of the wrapper class data type as boolean. What I have tried so far is given in the below javascript but somehow I couldn't able to get this work. What I am missing?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
 <apex:outputPanel id="employeePanel">
<apex:pageBlock id="employeeBlock">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!employeeList}" var="e" id="tblResults">
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!e.employee.Id}" id="namefield" />
        <apex:column id="selected">
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!e.isSelected}" id="inputId2" onClick="return enablePrimary(this.checked,'{!$Component.selectedprimary}');"/>
        </apex:column >
        <apex:column id="primary">
            <apex:facet name="header">Set as Primary</apex:facet>
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!e.isPrimary}" id="selectedprimary" disabled="true" onClick="allowOnePrimary(this);"/>
        </apex:column >
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">First Name</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!e.employee.First_Name__c}" id="fname"  />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Last Name">
            <apex:outputText value="{!e.employee.Last_Name__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Email">
            <apex:outputText value="{!e.employee.Email__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

```
//enable primary checkbox only when first checkbox is selected
function enablePrimary(selected,id1){
    if(selected == true){
        document.getElementById(id1).removeAttribute("disabled");
    }else{
        document.getElementById(id1).setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
        document.getElementById(id1).checked = false;
    }
}

function allowOnePrimary(checkbox) {
 var gv = document.getElementById('{!$Component.EmployeeForm}');
 var chk = gv.getElementsByTagName("selectedprimary");
 var row = checkbox.parentNode.parentNode;
 for(var i=0; i<chk.length; i++){
      if (chk[i].type == "checkbox") {
          alert('inside if');
                if (chk[i].checked && chk[i] != checkbox) {
                    chk[i].checked = false;
                    break;
                }
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: If you use jQuery, it can be done quite easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you using a class on your checkboxes like this:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!e.isPrimary}" styleClass="primaryCheckboxes" disabled="true" onClick="allowOnePrimary(this);"/>
```

Then you can select all checkboxes by requesting the class. Remove the checked state to these checkboxes. And finally set the checked state to the checkbox checked. Like this:

```
function allowOnePrimary(checkbox) {
 var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('primaryCheckboxes');
 for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){
     checkboxes[i].checked = false;
 }
 checkbox.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Woohoo that worked! I didn't think of getElementsByClassName and always trying to work with getElementsByTagName and not sure why it is not working though. Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome. It was not working because you were requesting by name but was setting the field id. To select an element by Id in Javascript you have to use: `getElementById`. But in HTML, id's are supposed to be unique. So that's better to use a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

This needs to have some modification;

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!e.isPrimary}" styleClass="primaryCheckboxes" disabled="true" onClick="allowOnePrimary(this);"
```

Instead above, use this one

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!e.isPrimary}" styleClass="primaryCheckboxes" disabled="false" onClick="allowOnePrimary(this);"
```